# Pasar un objeto de un fragment a una activity (que contiene otros fragments)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragment

Tengo 2 Activities: LoginActivity y MainActivity
LoginActivity posee 1 LoginFragment
MainActivity pose 2 fragmen → HomeFragment y ProfileFragment

Lo que hago es navegar desde el LoginFragment (navigate action) hacia el MainActivity cuyo "home" es el HomeFragment y le paso un String (email de usuario)

Mi problema es que en el HomeFragment no logro recuperar ese String.

**LoginFragment:**

```
            if(email.text.isNotEmpty() && pass.text.isNotEmpty())
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.text.toString(),
                    pass.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener{
                    if(it.isSuccessful){
              
                       
                            var action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToMainActivity(
                                email.text.toString())

                        v.findNavController().navigate(action)

                    }else{
                        vm.loginFail(v)
                    }
                }
        }
```

**login_navGraph** donde navego del LoginFragment a MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/login_navgraph"
    app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.example.mydti.fragments.LoginFragment"
        android:label="login_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_mainActivity"
            app:destination="@id/mainActivity" />
    </fragment>
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
        android:name="com.example.mydti.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="activity_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main"
        >
        <argument
            android:name="valor"
            app:argType="string" />
    </activity>
</navigation>
```

**ActivityMain** - donde tengo al HomeFragment como nav_host

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity"
    tools:menu="@menu/bottom_bar">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_home"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_bar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navgraph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="true"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="auto"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nav_host_home"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar">

    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**HomeFragment** - donde deberia recibir el String que envie del LoginFragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false)

        return v
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        name = v.findViewById(R.id.userName)  
      emailRecibido = MainActivityArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).valor
        name.text = emailRecibido

    }
```

Mis dudas son:
1- El String que envio va hacia al MainActivity o al HomeFragment ya que este es el nav_host del mainActivity.xml

2- Si el String va hacia el MainActivity, como lo recupero y lo envio al HomeFragment.

Espero haber sido claro en la explicacion y evidencia enviada.
Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Considera agregar a la pregunta el mensaje de error que recibes (como texto, no capturas de imagen). Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta. Te recomiendo que para comunicar entre diferentes partes de la App uses el [Componente de Navegación](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started?hl=es-419), es hacia donde está tendiendo Android actualmente. Es mucho más fácil pasar de un lado a otro y si necesitas pasar información también lo puedes hacer.

Comment: El componente de navegacion sirve tambien para comunicar diferentes fragments que se encuentren en diferentes Activities????
Gracias!

Comment: Sí, aunque si aprendes a usarlo bien, ni siquiera será necesario eso. Hoy día la tendencia apunta hacia un patrón conocido como [*Single Activity*](https://oozou.com/blog/reasons-to-use-android-single-activity-architecture-with-navigation-component-36) donde la App tiene una sola actividad y todo lo demás se realiza a través de fragmentos, simplificando todo y ayudando además a clarificar tu propia App, pues si lo piensas bien, ¿qué justifica que tengas diferentes Activity?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Listo, agregue codigo y explicacion mas detallada